# Apache HttpComponents Asyn GET: Entity content is too long

Tags: apache-camel, large-files, apache-httpcomponents

I am using Apache HttpComponents in a bean inside of Camel to try to write a job to download Apple's metadata database files. This is a list of every song in iTunes.  So, obviously it is big.  3.5+ GB.  I am trying to use Apache HttpComponents to make an asynchronous get request.  However, it seems that the size of the file being returned is too large.

```
try {
        httpclient.start();

        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(download);

        //Grab the archive.
        URIBuilder uriBuilder = new URIBuilder();
        uriBuilder.setScheme("https");
        uriBuilder.setHost("feeds.itunes.apple.com");
        uriBuilder.setPath("/feeds/epf-flat/v1/full/usa/" + iTunesDate + "/song-usa-" + iTunesDate + ".tbz");

        String endpoint = uriBuilder.build().toURL().toString();

        HttpGet getCall = new HttpGet(endpoint);

        String creds64 = new String(Base64.encodeBase64((user + ":" + password).getBytes()));
        log.debug("Auth: " + "Basic " + creds64);
        getCall.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + creds64);

        log.debug("About to download file from Apple: " + endpoint);

        Future<HttpResponse> future = httpclient.execute(getCall, null);

        HttpResponse response = future.get();

        fileOutputStream.write(EntityUtils.toByteArray(response.getEntity()));
        fileOutputStream.close();
```

Every time it return this:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.http.ContentTooLongException: Entity content is too long: 3776283429
at org.apache.http.concurrent.BasicFuture.getResult(BasicFuture.java:68)
at org.apache.http.concurrent.BasicFuture.get(BasicFuture.java:77)
at com.decibly.hive.songs.iTunesWrapper.getSongData(iTunesWrapper.java:89)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo.invoke(MethodInfo.java:407)
```

So, the size of the file in bytes is to big for a Java integer, which HttpComponents is using to track the response size.  I get that, wondering if there are any workarounds aside from dropping back a layer and calling the Java Net libraries directly.

Comment: Here is the code which check the response size. http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore-nio/4.2.2/org/apache/http/nio/protocol/BasicAsyncRequestConsumer.java#71

Comment: I think it is more like an issue of HttpComponents instead of camel.

Answer (score 2):

Use [HttpAsyncClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-4.1.x/index.html)
that is build on the top of http components and supports for Zero-Copy transfer.

See an example here: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-4.1.x/httpasyncclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/nio/client/ZeroCopyHttpExchange.java

Or simply, in your case

```
CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpclient = HttpAsyncClientBuilder.create().... 

     ZeroCopyConsumer<File> consumer = new ZeroCopyConsumer<File>(new File(download)) {
        @Override
        protected File process(
                final HttpResponse response,
                final File file,
                final ContentType contentType) throws Exception {
            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                throw new ClientProtocolException("Connection to host failed: " + response.getStatusLine());
            }
            return file;
        }
    };
    httpclient.execute(HttpAsyncMethods.createGet(endpoint), consumer, null, null).get();
```

The body of the response is directly saved to a file. The only limitation is given by the file system